# Determinant of an almost-diagonal block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let A be a $N\times N$ real symmetric matrix. I define the $N^2\times N^2$ matrix $\Sigma$ such that:
$$\Sigma_{n(i-1)+j, n(k-1)+l}=A_{j l} \delta_{i k}+\delta_{i l} \delta_{j k} b \quad \forall i, j, k, l \in \mathbb{N} \cap[1, n]$$

My question is, is there a way to efficiently find the determinant of $\Sigma$? I already know the eigenvalues and thus the determinant of $A$. If $b=0$ then we have a diagonal block matrix and the following holds: $|\Sigma|=|A|^N$. Of course, I would be interested in the case where $b\neq 0$.

In the case $N=2$:

$$\Sigma=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 A_{1,1}+b & A_{1,2} & 0 & 0 \\
 A_{2,1} & A_{2,2} & b & 0 \\
 0 & b & A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} \\
 0 & 0 & A_{2,1} & A_{2,2}+b \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

In the case $N=3$, the matrix $\Sigma$ looks like this:
$$\Sigma=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 A_{1,1}+b & A_{1,2} & A_{1,3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 A_{2,1} & A_{2,2} & A_{2,3} & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 A_{3,1} & A_{3,2} & A_{3,3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & b & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & b & 0 & A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} & A_{1,3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{2,1} & A_{2,2}+b & A_{2,3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{3,1} & A_{3,2} & A_{3,3} & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} & A_{1,3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b & A_{2,1} & A_{2,2} & A_{2,3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{3,1} & A_{3,2} & A_{3,3}+b \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Playing around, I found that:

In the case $N=2$:

$|\Sigma|=|A+bI|(|A|-|bI|)$

In the case $N=3$:

$|\Sigma|=|A+bI|\left(|A|^2-b^2\operatorname{Tr}(A)|A|-|bI|^2+b^4\operatorname{Tr}(\Lambda^2A)\right)$

Where $\operatorname{Tr}\left(\Lambda^2A\right)$ is the trace of the $k$th exterior power of A, taken from this formula:
$$
|A-bI|=-\sum_{k=0}^{n} b^{n-k}(-1)^{k} \operatorname{tr}\left(\Lambda^{k} A\right)
$$
I would hope that there is a relatively simple formula for general $N$.

Any ideas or remarks are always appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This matrix is block-diagonal. You must compute the determinant for every diagonal block. As you know the det of every $A_{i,j}$ you can compute this one easy as well

Comment: I am sorry if it is obvious, but I cannot see how $\Sigma$ can be written as a block-diagonal matrix?

Comment: With $N=2$ you take the$2N\times 2N$ Matrix as a block. It is a block of blocks, therefore not that easy to see. Rules of the determinant allow for recursively applying block structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think it is possible to write $\Sigma$ as a block matrix of square matrices such that $\Sigma$ becomes block-diagonal. Could you show me how you did it?

Comment: Let $\Sigma_1 = \begin{pmatrix} A_{1,1}+ b &A_{1,2} \\ A_{2,1} &A_{2,2}\end{pmatrix}$ (in the case of N=2). Then you can write $\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \Sigma_2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I see. Unfortunately it is not correct: $\Sigma\neq\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\Sigma_{1} & 0 \\
0 & \Sigma_{2}
\end{array}\right)$. The anti-diagonal blocks contain a b element, which you did not include.

Comment: Let $B=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & b \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$. Then $\Sigma=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\Sigma_{1} & B^T \\
B & \Sigma_{2}
\end{array}\right)$

Comment: Oh My god, I'm as blind as a bat. Sorry, I did not see the $b$s there...